# $\text{Hom}$ of irreducible modules and restrictions

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

This question is in reference to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503040v3.pdf). 
More specifically it is in reference to the proof of proposition 1.4 on page 8.

First a defintion:  Let $A$ be a semisimple finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and let $B\subset A$ be a subalgebra. Define $Z(A,B)$ to be all the elements of $A$ that commute with $B.$

Let $V$ be an irreducible representation of $A$ and $W$ be an irreducible representation of $B$.  I am reading a paper that claims:

> $\text{Hom}_B(W ,res_B V)$ is an $A$-module and that it is an irreducible $Z(A,B)$ module.

I don't understand why $\text{Hom}_B(W, res_B V)$ is an $A$-module. We need to define an action of $A$ on $\text{Hom}_B(W, res_B V)$ and the natural action we might want to consider is $(af)(w) := af(w).$  But this does not define an action when $A$ does not commute with $B$ since 
$$(af)(bw) = af(bw)= abf(w) \neq baf(w) = b(af)(w)$$
when $b$ and $a$ don't commute.

So first I would like to understand why $\text{Hom}_B(W,V)$ is an $A$-module and then why it is an irreducible $Z(A,B)$-module. Any hints suggestions or references are welcome.

Comment: What is the paper? Link to it?

Comment: @Grothendieck Just edited and added a link to the paper